# Zend session in multi module website

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to a write a multi-module application in ZF2 but i am facing some weird problem of session.

Session are getting destroyed automatically when i am switching the modules in browser.

Is there any way to share single session accros all the modules.

Thanks

Comment: Show some code you done for set session & get session

Comment: What are the domains / urls of each module?

Comment: @M.M. Its sort of
www.anydomain.com/module1
www.anydomain.com/module2
www.anydomain.com/module3

I am creating a session from module1 and trying to access that session on module2 its just resetting the session
www.anydomain.com/module4

Comment: If all your modules are sharing domain it should not be a problem at all. Are you using ZF's authentication adapter? How are you checking if user's authenticated in each module? Please share some code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use ZF2 session Manager?
if yes, you probably configure your session in a single module and the other can't find the config

Comment: I am using session Manager. and i have noticed that session is getting destroyed when i am trying to go tp a url which is not using View (I have written some web services and i have used separate module for web services). do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Can you give your code? (2 parts: hen you call your session and get it, and when you call it and can't find the session)  and how did you config the session?

Comment: Here is the link for sample codes https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101837095/configAndSample.txt

Comment: You got a lot of action on your sessions, try to comment your factories and bootstrap action to see a minimum of code, cause you use correctly containers and that must be work =) The problem probably come form the factorie on the step: Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager); (if you always fail the if/else before)

Comment: I have noticed a very strange behavior. Like if i am not using any ViewModel to render the output and just trying ti return response as web service response then its creating a new session with different session id and that basically flushing the session data. Have you ever encountered such problem? Any idea?

Comment: basically to return a viewModel, you have to possibility : __1)__ return array(); __2)__ $view = new ViewModel(); return $view;  -  Try to "return array();" after your print_r() EDIT : i never encountered this problem ^^

Comment: I am using same method to return ViewModel. And its working fine if am returning ViewModel but its destroying the session when i am just returning array or any other variable rather than ViewModel.

Comment: wich version of ZF2 are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 2.3

Comment: did you use the ResponseObject when you want to return something else? (it's done for that =) )

Comment: Yeah I am using response object. If i am using ResponseObject and return it its just destroying the session in other hand if i am using a ViewModel and rendering the ResponseObject output into ViewModel then its working properly.

Comment: you got same prob if you clear onBootstrap and get getServiceConfig? i think the prob is here cause you param session in the function Onbootstrap : __$sessionConfig->setOptions(array(
        'remember_me_seconds' => 2419200,
        'use_cookies' => true,
        'cookie_httponly' => true,
         ));__